# Access Report - TextBox disappears in Print Preview

Tags: ms-access-2007

SOLVED BY RECREATING THE REPORT FROM THE SAME QUERY AGAIN AND PASTING THE ELEMENTS OVER AGAIN. - anyone have any insight as to why this would happen?

***Details:*** Access 2007, tried bringing it to the front, resetting control source

I have a generated report in Access that generally works as you would expect. However one of the textboxes created by the wizard isn't working. In the record view, everything looks great. When I go to print preview or print the report, the textbox just disapears. The record source seems to be set in the same fashion as the others and everything looks alright.

The Report View
[image: Report View]

The Print Preview
[image: Print Preview]

I have no idea what would make this happen. Every other report generated from the database works normally, so I'm at a loss.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Since you have other reports very similar, you can swap out elements, and so on.  Try deleting all the elements in that header area and pasting in the equivalents from another report.  Experiment!

Comment: It seems that pasting the same control into a different report works in the different report. I'm going to try recreating some elements and see what happens.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but copying over the exact same element from a different report seems to work. I have no idea. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Glad it worked.  With dozens of properties to wade through, replacement or rebuild is an appealing and efficient approach.  To answer your question WHY? ... sometimes you never get to learn the why!  Objects can even suffer corruptions, become glitchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property called `DisplayWhen` with the options `Always`, `Print Only` and `Screen Only`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195851%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: +1 -- I think this is a likely cause.  I don't know much about version 2007, and I couldn't give precise instructions, so I didn't post it.